# Nestjs request, interceptor in testing

Tags: testing, request, nestjs

I have RateUpInterceptor and this add count rate 1

```
@Injectable()
export class RateUpInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const http = context.switchToHttp();
    const req = http.getRequest<IRequestAugmented>();
    const res = http.getResponse<Response>();
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(async () => {
        /** COUNT PLUS 1 **/
        console.log('A');
      }),
      catchError((e) => {
        return throwError(e);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

```
describe('RateUpInterceptor', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let module: TestingModule;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UserModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
          useFactory: () => {
            return new RateUpInterceptor();
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();

  });
  
  it('test', async () => {
    request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get(`valid url`)
      .auth(token, { type: 'bearer' })
      .expect(200).end(async () => {
        console.log('B');      
      });
  });  
});
```

I tested this interceptor by e2e test using request.

I thought that after global interceptor "console.log('B')" executes

but result was different...
result wait this

```
B
A
```

How can I fix this order?

Comment: Why do you want to invert the order? The interceptor should execute before the route is executed, not after?

Comment: @Baboo_ RateUpInterceptor count plus 1 and i wanna result of after RateUpInterceptor in order to check rate. but in .end() count doesn't plus 1...

Comment: It's normal beause at the moment the interceptor only executes `console.log('A');` unless the code provided here is not the one in your file

Comment: it is an example. i think that after interceptor executes ```console.log('A');```, end executes ```console.log('B')```. is this wrong? @Baboo_

Comment: What `request` is doing is calling your api like a user would do. So Nestjs processes the request like this: `middlewares before route -> route -> middlewares after route`. In your case, interceptor is a middleware executed after the route because of this line of code: `next.handle().pipe`. First you call `next` and then you add one.

Comment: What happens when you put `await` before the `request` in your test case